# Azure SQL stored procedure using MVC Application with SendGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, azure-sql-database

I'm currently developing an appointment system for a university project using C# MVC. I would like to send automated emails through SendGrid which I'm using elsewhere in my project.

My system and sql database are deployed on Azure, I've done some research and it has directed me towards sql stored procedures to pick up the appointment times  and email address from the database automatically.

I'm wondering if this is the best way to create this functionality and if anyone has any good articles or tutorials for doing this or something similar?

I'd appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SendGrid service from Azure Marketplace as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email). You can create an email object as shown below:

```
var msg = new SendGridMessage();

msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("dx@example.com", "SendGrid DX Team"));

var recipients = new List<EmailAddress>
{
    new EmailAddress("jeff@example.com", "Jeff Smith"),
    new EmailAddress("anna@example.com", "Anna Lidman"),
    new EmailAddress("peter@example.com", "Peter Saddow")
};
msg.AddTos(recipients);

msg.SetSubject("Testing the SendGrid C# Library");

msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, "Hello World plain text!");
msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, "<p>Hello World!</p>");
```

After creating an email message, you can send it using SendGrid's API. Alternatively, you may use [.NET's built in library](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/csharp.html#-Using-NETs-Builtin-SMTP-Library).

Sending email requires that you supply your SendGrid API Key. If you need details about how to configure API Keys, please visit [SendGrid's API Keys documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/api_keys.html).

The following examples show how to send an email message using the SendGrid Web API with a console application.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

namespace Example
{
    internal class Example
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Execute().Wait();
        }

        static async Task Execute()
        {
            var apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "DX Team"),
                Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
                PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"));
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also send email from ASP .NET Core API using MailHelper class as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#how-to-send-email-from-asp-net-core-api-using-mailhelper-class).

Comment: Hi Alberto, thank you for your reply. The information you have provided is very helpful, do you know how I would have the email triggered by the data from my SQL database using this method?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples) to retrieve data from database.

You also could use [Entity Framework code first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) to access data in MVC.

This is about [Entity Framework database first](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-entity-framework-using-database-first-approach/), you could also refer to.

If you have any problem with sendgrid, you could refer to Alberto, he gave the detailed reply.

Comment: Hi Joey, thank you for your reply. I have followed those steps and have a full system built using the entity framework, specifically I'm looking for information on triggering  an email using azure and data from my SQL database?

Comment: https://www.codit.eu/blog/2017/08/21/exploring-azure-event-grid/. Based on the article I shared above an INSERT on a table is an event that may trigger an action.


"Extend existing workflows by triggering a Logic App once there is a new record in your database". You can also use Azure Automation

Comment: https://www.codit.eu/blog/2017/08/21/exploring-azure-event-grid/. Based on this article an INSERT on a table is an event that may trigger an action using Azure Event Grid. Azure Automation and powershell may be another option.